# Update is not applicable to your computer

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, windows-update, windows

I am running Windows Web Server 2008 R2 SP1 and its a 64-bit.

I am trying to apply this hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368 and it becoming TOTALLY impossible? i have double checked and indeed this hotfix isn't installed on my server currently and I really really need it, every time i try to install it i get "The update is not applicable to your computer".

How come? is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

It is already included in Service Pack 1. So no need to install it again. This is what the message tells you.

Comment: So why is a downloadable package available for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition? I was getting the same message before I installed SP1, I installed SP1 to see if it would make a difference and it didn't. This message comes up for both Windows Server 2008 R2 and R2 SP1, at least for me, I have spoken to my hosting company and they were unable to install the hotfix themselves.

Comment: The KB doesn't list W2K8 R2 Web Edition as needing this update, so it's not applicable to your server, hence the message when you try to install it. I'm not sure why you're trying to install it when it's clearly not applicable.

Comment: I thought that the "Windows Server 2008 R2" download would include all the editions. So what are the options for the 2008 R2 Web edition?

Comment: There is an auto-update available called "Microsoft Update". If it doesn't find a patch, then there is no patch! Why? There is no need for a patch. Why? Ask Microsoft.